# hierarchical view of maven projects netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

If I have a multi-level Maven project in Netbeans it offers a project view where the parent project shows the modules in a Modules folder. If I open one of these modules it moves it down to the same level as the parent project.

[image]

This is a little frustrating because when we are working with a lot of modules, we lose hierarchical perspective, and we need to name our projects very carefully so that we know what is going on.

Is there anyway to have a view like this :

[image]

When I open up one of the modules it stays inside the parent (a bit like windows explorer). It would help me keep perspective on things much much better.

Here is another view of how i would like it:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that is possible through standard NB UI. NB mailing list/forum might be more suitable for this question. [E.g.](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projectextension.html)

Answer (score 2):

it's not possible. There are some enhancement requests filed for it however the biggest roadblock here is that netbeans has opened projects as scope for various things, like refactoring, go to type etc. With allowing all submodules to be automatically considered "opened", one would fairly fast hit the memory and other resources limits, even with moderately big multiprojects. So you always have to explicitly say what you want to have opened to be able to manage the resources.

Comment: but wouldnt this just be a 'view' issue? I mean as soon as the [+] is clicked then the project goes into memory, and when you collapse it, it frees the memory.

Comment: Well, possibly yes. It opens up a can of worms I described in the answer. Please note that if you only have the parent pom opened, none of the child projects or their classpaths are visible to the IDE. So you would not be able to work with any of the child projects effectively anyway unless you open them (and 'fill up' the open projects lists)

Comment: Ive added another image. It seems like it is only a view issue. If you double click it, it can either explode at the same level, or inline with the directory structure

Comment: Unfortunately not entirely just view. Once you open a file from a non-opened project (like a java file) you will quickly notice it's not 100% the same experience. Eg. Find Usages, Refactoring and other features don't work the same. For example see https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228560

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Netbeans which you can view maven projects (and their child) hierarchically: [Maven Hierarchical View](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/45180)

Here https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/netbeans-ide-81-plugin:-maven-hierarchical-view you can find more info.

Although this question is asked some years ago but I now find an answer which I think could be useful for others who search about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible using a Netbeans GUI, but you can use a Maven command for that:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```